# How much lisp to implement in C before writing extension in itself?

Tags: c, parsing, lisp, common-lisp, interpreter

I am implementing a lisp interpreter in C, i have implemented along with few primitives like cons , car, cdr , eq, basic arithmetic stuff.

Just before i was starting to implement define and lambda it occurred to me that i need to implement an environment. I am unsure if i could implement it in lisp itself.

My intent is to implement minimal amount of lisp so that i could write extension to the language in itself. I am not sure how much is minimal, Would implementing FFI Qualify as minimal ?

Comment: I'd think you'd at least need to implement the special forms and operators.

Comment: You don't necessarily need lambda or any environment, see my approach explained here: https://combinatorylogic.wordpress.com/2015/01/14/bootstrapping-a-compiler/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on the meaning that you give to the word “minimal”.

Given your question, and assuming that you don't want to make an implementation competing with the nowdays fine implementations of Common Lisp and Schema, my hypothesis is that with “minimal” you intend: [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), that is capable of expressing any computation expressible in a general purpose programming language.

With this assumption, you need to implement three other things:

1. conditional forms  (`cond`)
2. lambda expressions (`lambda`)
3. a way of defining recursive lambda expression (`labels` or `defun`)

Your interpreter then should be able to evaluate forms. This should be sufficient to have a language equivalent to the initial [LISP](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/history/lisp/lisp.html), that allow to express in the language any computable function.

Comment: Thanks For the reply, By minimal i meant how much lisp i need to implement that i stay close to first principles and yet the interpreter should be good enough to evaluate its own code "A meta circular evaluator". 

Then my next plan of action is to write a set of lisp library functions that could output nasm assembler code, and in affect could compile the lisp interpreter written in itself to machine code. Thus completing the cycle.



Also i have no intent of competing with mainstream LISP Compilers.

Comment: "Should be good enough to evaluate its own code" means exactly to be "Turing complete". So that you could rewrite the interpreter in your Lisp.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you are talking about first writing a LISP interpreter. You have a lot of choices to take when it comes to scoping, LISP1 vs LISP2 since these questions alter the implementation core. An interpreter is a general purpose program that reads and evaluates code. It can support abstractions but it won't extend itself by making more native stuff.

If you are interested in such stuff you can perhaps make a compiler instead. Eg. there are many Sceme like subsets that compiles to C or Java code, but you can make your own VM. Thus it can indeed compile itself to be run on it's own target machine (self hosting) if all the forms and procedures you use has been implemented using the primitives supported by the compiler.

Making a dumb compiler is not much difference from making an interpreter. That is very clear if yo've watched the [SICP videos](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/) (10A is about compilation, 7A-B is about interpreters)

The environment can be a chain of pairs just as in a LISP interpreter. It would be difficult to implement the environment of itself in LISP without making it a very difficult Lisp language to use (unless it's compiled that is)
You may use the data structures of lisp and the primitives from the C code though.

Making a FFI is a fast way to give your language lots of features. It solves the chicken and egg problem by using other peoples work from within your language. In fuses the top (primitives and syntax) and the bottom layer (a runtime) of your system. It's the ultimate primitive and you can think of it as system call or message bus to the runtime.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest to read [Queinnec's book: *Lisp In Small Pieces*](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html). It is a book dedicated entirely to answer your question, and it explains in detail the many trade-offs and the internals of Lisp implementations and definitions, by giving many explained examples of Lisp interpreters and compilers.

You might also consider using [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/). You could be interested in the internals of M.Serrano's [Bigloo](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Manuel.Serrano/bigloo/) & [Hop](http://hop.inria.fr/) implementations. You might even look inside my [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) lisp-like language to customize the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)
 compiler.

You also need to learn more about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) (you might read the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/)). You could use [Boehm's conservative Garbage Collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) (or something else, e.g. my [Qish](http://starynkevitch.net/basile/qishintro.html) or [MPS](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/)) or write your own GC.

You may want to learn more about [Chicken](http://code.call-cc.org/), [Scheme 48](http://s48.org/), [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) and read their papers and look inside their code.

See also [J.Pitrat's blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/): it is not about Lisp (but about bootstrapping strong AI) and has several fascinating entries related to bootstrapping.

Comment: I started reading this book recently after so many yrs of asking this question, and i must say what a brilliant book on implementing lisp compilers.